# Android animation: rotation of a View inside RelativeLayout around a pivot point

Tags: android, android-animation

What is the best way to perform a rotation around a pivot point of a Custom View inside a FrameLayout?

In particular I want the center of the FrameLayout as the pivot of the rotation.

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/annulus_frame"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvRightEye"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <com.mycustomview.AnnulusView
            android:id="@+id/anim_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
```